# How to set up navigation between tab pages in Ionic 4 Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes

I have an application that shows a tab page at first. Within any of the tabs, the user can navigate to another page which is also a tab page. However, using the `<ion-back-button>` does not work for me as expected.

---

To illustrate the problem, I have taken the sample starter tab app of Ionic and extended it with a second tab page. This is the setup:

First tab page (TabsPage):

- /tabs/tab1/
- /tabs/tab2/
- /tabs/tab3/

Second tab page (OtherTabsPage):

- /other-tabs/other-tab1/

---

While I managed to set up the navigation from any of the three first tabs to the new tab page, the navigation back (`<ion-back-button>`) seems to be broken.

As this might be a bit complicated to understand, I have created a full Stackblitz example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-hxxnpm

---

Reproduce the problem like this:

- Open tab2
- Click the button ("open nested tab") to go to the new tab page (other-tab1)
- Now click the back button on the top left, you will end up on tab1 instead of tab2

Is this a bug or do I have an error in my routing setup?

---

**EDIT:**

Ionic has classified this as bug so far. Will update if there is an answer: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19801